# Why is JScrollPane not working?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

When I comment out frame.add(hidden) it only shows the text area. When I don't comment it out, it only shows a large gray box with a grayed out Scrollbar.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Panlindrome{
    public Panlindrome(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Panlindrome?");
        frame.setSize(240,320);
        //frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        JTextArea inputText = new JTextArea(30,1);
        inputText.setLineWrap(true);

        JScrollPane hidden = new JScrollPane(inputText);
        hidden.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        frame.add(inputText);
        //frame.add(hidden);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Panlindrome check = new Panlindrome();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Java. I think this is because you can only add Swing widgets to one parent; thus, `inputText` is being removed from the scroll pane when you add it directly to the frame.

Comment: `frame.add(inputText)` will remove the text area from the scroll pane, so adding the scroll pane after this call will result in an empty scroll pane (and the `inputText` been removed from the frame, because that's how `BorderLayout` works)...

Comment: @mspencer I would say you need to make that an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't add inputText to the frame; only add hidden.

The content of the scroll pane is already a child of the scroll pane. If you also try to add it to the frame (actually the frame's content pane, but whatever) as well, it will be in two places at once, which doesn't work.